# high volume warning window cause system halt

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio, system-apps, 7.0-nougat

I'm using Nexus 6 for a long time, but after some *safety update*, a problem came up. Before, when you raise the volume above a certain level, the system would warn you that it is bad for your hearing abilities. But now, the warning is gone, and instead, it would make the system app stop, like an unhandled exception is thrown, and the app will reboot. I guess the app is called `System Interface` or something similar.

Other info:

```
Phone: Nexus 6, not rooted
System version: problem occured at Android 6 (Marshmallow)
                but in Android 7 (Nougat) it is still there
Problem occur time: When earphone was plugged in, and volume is turned up.
```